# How to .htaccess on IIS6 with php5?

Tags: iis

I am new on Microsoft products.

On my server installed FastCGI, and should I need install ISAPI for mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this help guide here installing the ISAPI_Rewrite module here:

http://jkshay.com/implementing-an-isapi-rewrite-for-iis-6/

Comment: So that FastCgi cannot make it for mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to perform rewrites is not built in to IIS6 (IIS7 has it).  In order to achieve this functionality in IIS6, we'll need a third-party utility.  As Nugget pointed out, I have an article on my blog regarding the configuration of a donation-ware product that achieves this.

Side note - while it is donation-ware, I've been unable to contact the author of the product, and all donate links in the documentation (at last check) are dead.